# Set different outline offsets for each side

Tags: html, css, border, padding, offset

In CSS, I can set an outline width `outline: 1px solid red` and I can set its offset (similar to padding) with `outline-offset: 5px`.

However, this method does not allow for the shorthand method used by `padding`, like `border: 1px 2px 3px 4px` and there doesn't seem to be an `outline-offset-left: 1px` option.

So, is there a way to set different offsets on each side for a CSS outline? Note that I don't want to use `padding`; it would offset the outlines how I'd like, but it would also add extra padding to elements where I don't want to, which is the whole reason I am using `outline` in the first place.

Comment: _"So, is there a way to set different offsets on each side for a CSS outline?"_ Nope.

Comment: Thanks, that's quite a limitation. Any particular reason it's like that?

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice hack you can do to achieve the effect you are after, but it probably has to be done on a case-by-case basis.

My scenario was that I had some content with padding, which contained several html elements including some anchors/links. Let's imagine the scss is something like this:

```
.contanier {
  padding: 15px;
  > a {
    padding: 8px 0;
  }
}
```

When focusing on an anchor the `outline` is pretty much touching the text and generally looks poor. Now, as you said, adding left/right padding to the anchors for the sake of an outline would throw off the layout of the content. The anchors would no longer appear inline with other elements in the container such as a heading/paragraph/image/what have you.

So to resolve the problem I added padding to the anchors, and negated it by setting a negative margin:

```
> a {
  margin: 0 -4px;
  padding: 8px 4px;
}
```

Now I have complete control of how the focus appears. There are some use-cases where this solution does not work, for example, if your anchors have a background colour. But for most cases it works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

According to [**MDN's docs on Outline**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline), the only properties to set on outline are:

- *outline-style*
- *outline-width*
- *outline-color*

To which `outline` is a shorthand to concatenate those properties. But there's no *side* definition, due to the following fact:

> Outlines may be non-rectangular. They are rectangular in Gecko/Firefox. But e.g. Opera draws a non-rectangular shape around a construct like this...

Since they may not be rectancular, it wouldn't make sense to be able to define *left*, *top*, etc, properties...

Comment: There is also an `outline-offset` property which the OP is talking about. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline-offset